# Problems understanding IoC with dependency injection

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to get my head around IoC w. dependency injection and I have followed this blogpost from Joel Abrahamsson: http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/inversion-of-control-introduction-with-examples-in-dotnet

I have set up my projects like this:

- Model
- Interfaces
- Controllers
- DAL

And my classes is as follows:

**Car**

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

**CarController**

```
public class CarController
 {
     private readonly ICar _carInterface;

     public CarController(ICar car)
     {
         _carInterface = car;
     }

     public void SaveCar(Car car)
     {
          _carInterface.SaveCar(car);
     }
}
```

**ICar interface**

```
public interface ICar
{
    void SaveCar(Car car);
}
```

**DbCar**

```
public class DbCar: ICar
{
    public void SaveCar(Car car)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now, on the UI, I'm not sure what to do with this ;-) I can sure enough make the Car object that I need, but when new'ing up a CarController, it (of course) expects an ICar interface which I can't give it.

I've got a feeling that I have misunderstood something along the way of reading Joels (great) article :-) And I was hoping that maybe someone could shed a light on what I have missed/misunderstood.

Any help/hint is greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance.

All the best,

Bo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `ICar` is not an interface to a car. Rather it's an interface to a repository for saving cars in. So it should be called `ICarRepository` (or possibly `IGarage`.)

You say:

> but when new'ing up a CarController, it (of course) expects an ICar
>   interface which I can't give it.

Why not? You have an implementation, `DbCar`. Why can't you give it one of those?

You asked in a comment about this expression:

```
new CarController(new DbCar())
```

Specifically that by writing that line of code, you've tied the controller to a specific implementation of the car repository.

That's true, but only in that case. Somewhere else in a unit test you could write:

```
new CarController(new FakeCarRepository())
```

The `CarController` class is an independent module, and its dependency on other things is clear from its constructor's parameter list.

IoC or "dependency injection" frameworks are libraries that provide a standard way to construct classes such as `CarController`, so that the parameters it needs will be specified in a config file. But that's probably overkill for a simple app.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your input :-) Ahh, so the ICar should rather be an interface for the data access layer than the Car object itself? It should then be named something like ICarDb or something. I was thinking of it as the "normal" way of using interfaces, I guess.

Comment: Only thing that I find a bit dirty is to have data access layer object on the UI (for passing it into the Controllers constructor) ?

Comment: If the UI needs to get data, it needs access to the data access layer, right?

Comment: Note that the point is to give the controller an interface for getting data, rather than giving it a specific implementation that needs a database. That way, you can construct the controller (for example) with a fake implementation for testing purposes. It's not bound to the database-specific stuff, only to an interface that has the minimum methods needed to get data *from somewhere*.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, but when you do this: new CarController(new DbCar()) it seems to be a concrete class, or is it just me? ;-) Edit: sorry if I'm a tad slow on this :-)

Answer (score 0):

To do Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control properly, you should adhere to Interface-Based development (the "I" in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles). Below is how I'd organize your classes and interfaces for being able to pull this off to its fullest extent.

**ICar interface**

```
public interface ICar
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Brand { get; set; }
    string Year { get; set; }
}
```

**Car**

```
public class Car : ICar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

**ICarRepository interface**

```
public interface ICarRepository
{
    void SaveCar(ICar car);
}
```

**CarRepository**

```
public class CarRepository : ICarRepository
{
    public void SaveCar(ICar car)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**ICarController interface**

```
public interface ICarController
{
     void SaveCar(ICar car);
}
```

**CarController**

```
public class CarController : ICarController
{
     private readonly ICarRepository _carRepository;

     public CarController(ICarRepository carRepository)
     {
         _carRepository = carRepository;
     }

     public void SaveCar(ICar car)
     {
          _carRepository.SaveCar(car);
     }
}
```

**Then you can:**

```
ICarRepository carRepository = new CarRepository();
ICarController carController = new CarController(carRepository);
ICar carOne = new Car { Id = 1, Brand = "Ford", Year = "2010" };
ICar carTwo = new Car { Id = 2, Brand = "Dodge", Year = "1999" };

carController.SaveCar(carOne);
carController.SaveCar(carTwo);
```

Comment: The `ICar` interface interface it useles, since there is no reason to abstract a DTO. You can completely ditch the `ICar` interface.

Comment: Not necessarily - if you're moving into an environment where you're doing automated unit testing, being able to mock `ICar`s is essential.

Comment: But what part of `Car` do you actually want to mock? It contains no behavior.

Comment: `I` in SOLID stands for interface segregation. i.e. you should create as small and specific interfaces as possible instead of god-object like interfaces.